# IDENT_CURRENT RETURN NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server that inserts and should show the `id` of the inserted record but when I use `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `IDENT_CURRENT` it returns null.

Table structure:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Idfac
    START WITH 2000
    INCREMENT BY 1;
GO

CREATE TABLE Factura
(
    idFactura [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Idfac),
    Nombre_sucursal [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    Nombre_cliente [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    Numero_factura [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    Fecha Datetime,
    Subtotal DECIMAL(18, 2) ,
    IGV AS CAST(Subtotal * 0.18 AS decimal(18,2)),
    Total DECIMAL(18, 2) ,

    CONSTRAINT chk_Subtotal 
        CHECK(Subtotal IS NULL OR Subtotal <> 0),
    CONSTRAINT chk_total 
        CHECK (Total IS NULL OR Total <> 0) 
);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_RegistrarFactura
    @Nombre_sucursal varchar(20),
    @Nombre_cliente varchar(100),
    @Numero_factura varchar(10),
    @Fecha Datetime,
    @Subtotal DECIMAL(18, 2) 
AS
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO Factura (Nombre_sucursal, Nombre_cliente, Numero_factura, Fecha, Subtotal, total)
    VALUES (@Nombre_sucursal, @Nombre_cliente, @Numero_factura, @Fecha, @Subtotal, @Subtotal * 0.18 + @Subtotal)

    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Factura') AS Result;
END
```

[image]

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` is for `IDENTITY`. You are using a `SEQUENCE` object. You'll need to use the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Also, the `RETURN` value of a procedure denotes its success; `0` for success and anything else for failure.

Comment: @Larnu you have an example?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) has plenty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a `SEQUENCE` for the default of the IdFactura column, you're not going to be able to use `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `IDENT_CURRENT`. Instead, you're going to need to use `OUTPUT` clause for the `INSERT` command.

I changed your procedure to match what you're trying to achieve.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_RegistrarFactura
    @Nombre_sucursal varchar(20),
    @Nombre_cliente varchar(100),
    @Numero_factura varchar(10),
    @Fecha Datetime,
    @Subtotal DECIMAL(18, 2)
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE (
        [Return] INT);
    INSERT INTO Factura (Nombre_sucursal, Nombre_cliente, Numero_factura, Fecha, Subtotal, total)
    OUTPUT Inserted.idFactura INTO @ReturnTable
    VALUES (@Nombre_sucursal, @Nombre_cliente, @Numero_factura, @Fecha, @Subtotal, @Subtotal * 0.18 + @Subtotal)

    RETURN(SELECT [Return] FROM @ReturnTable)
END
```

Using your sample:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[USP_RegistrarFactura]
     @Nombre_sucursal = N'La Molina',
     @Nombre_cliente = N'Mario',
     @Numero_factura = N'001230036',
     @Fecha = N'2021-11-10',
     @Subtotal = 150

SELECT 'Return Value' = @Return_value
```

The result as follows:

[image]

PS: It's important to note that you're trying to use the returned value of the procedure. Take a look at the documentation for [Returning Data Using a Return Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-a-return-code).